# Why is a folder in Mail favourites greyed out and how to reactivate it?

Tags: mail.app

In the favourites section of Mail (in screenshot at location (1)), a folder is greyed out. It cannot be selected, also nothing happens if I hover over it. What could be the reason? Please note, the folder was before in another section ("On my Mac", (2)), I probably moved it to the favourites section by accident. Also I cannot drag it back to any of the non-favourite sections.

Searching for this kind of problem was unfortunately not successful.

[image]

Comment: The favorites thing shouldn't matter - favorites also normally appear in both places. You can right click on a folder to add and remove from favorites.

Comment: What type of mail account is it? Gmail, etc? And, do you know if it's setup with IMAP, POP, or something else? Typically a mailbox will be dimmed when it's inaccessible like you don't have permission to access it. Check your username and password.

Comment: @Alex Need to check